# How to debug-print when writing NeoVim Lua?

Tags: neovim, init.lua

While writing/debugging my nvim lua, I would like to have a running log file that I can monitor with `tail -f` in a side terminal.

I couldn't find a good answer to this question via Google. Adding what I came up with here for others to find (and improve).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with. I'm a Lua-noob, so please help improve if needed. I'm playing around with creating my own Nvim config to share with my work-group (bad working name: nvimide).

To monitor:

```
tail -f /tmp/nvim.USER/nvimide.log
```

###### **`init.lua`**

```lua
nvimide = {
    debug_restart = false,
    debug = true,
    log_fh = nil,
    log = function(...)
        if nvimide.debug then
            local objects = {}
            for i = 1, select('#', ...) do
                local v = select(i, ...)
                table.insert(objects, vim.inspect(v))
            end
            nvimide.log_fh:write(table.concat(objects, '\n') .. '\n')
            nvimide.log_fh:flush()
        end
    end,
    script_path = function()
        return debug.getinfo(2, "S").source:sub(2)
    end,
}
if nvimide.debug then
    nvimide.log_fh = io.open("/tmp/nvim." .. os.getenv("USER") .. "/nvimide.log", nvimide.debug_restart and 'w' or 'a')
end
nvimide.log("Enter " .. nvimide.script_path())
vim.g.mapleader = " "
require("config.lazy")
require("config.keymaps")
require("config.autocmds")
nvimide.log("Leave " .. nvimide.script_path())
```

Comment: `E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: ...: attempt to index field 'log_fh' (a nil value)`

Comment: I just tried and it works. You can see that when nvimide.debug is set to true, I define nvimide.log_fh.